# How to show that $\left\lfloor{N/3}\right\rfloor < \left\lfloor{\left({N + 3}\right)/p}\right\rfloor$ has no solution for $p \ge 5$ where $N \ge p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I can see this numerically however I am having difficulty proving this by number theory methods.  Both $N$ and $p$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$\lfloor \frac{N}{3} \rfloor
< \lfloor \frac{N+3}{p} \rfloor
$,
then
$\frac{N}{3} 
<  \frac{N+3}{p}
$
so that
$pN < 3(N+3)$
or
$N(p-3) < 9$.

But
$N \ge p \ge 5$
so that
$N(p-3)
\ge 5\cdot 2
= 10
$,
which contradicts this.

This was surprisingly easy.

Comment: This looks good but if I apply this to the case $\left\lfloor{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor < \left\lfloor{\frac{N+2}{p}}\right\rfloor$ for $p \ge 3$, then I get $p N < 2 \left({N + 2}\right)$ or $N \left({p - 2}\right) < 4$.  But in this case $N \ge p \ge 3$ so that $N \left({p - 2}\right) \ge 3 \cdot 1 = 3$ which is not a contradiction.  See $p$ are primes.  This case also has no solution as determined by numerical methods for $p \ge 3$.

Comment: I am thinking that since $x - 1 < \left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor \le x$ that perhaps we apply all possible cases and take the minimum or restricted set of all three possible (I think) cases?